# Where do I find an overview of all python functions for QGIS

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, qgis, pyqgis

I'm making a plug-in for QGIS, using the python language.
I've looked everywhere but I can't seem to find a good overview of all the QGIS functions there are usable in the python script.

For example, let's say I selected a Polygon as a geometry.
I know I can calculate the area of the polygon using `.geometry().area()`

But where do I find an overview of ALL the things I can do with this geometry?
The QGIS Cookbook gives a few examples but not everything.

Comment: I have not used QGIS but have you tried a dir of whatever you are importing into Python?  See this Q&A and maybe look for others using the keyword introspection

Comment: There is this website: http://qgis.org/api/
But why is it all c++ language? Where's the Python one?

Comment: I wonder if this would be better asked, for those who will need the answers in the future, on gis.stackexchange.com

Comment: Totally agree with you. Can the whole question be copied there so that it exists on both sites?

Comment: @PaulH Just posted the answer in GIS.SE too, there was a similar question since 2014: http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/188707/4972

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There you go:

A diagram of the main PyQGIS relationships (by Thomas Gratier): https://raw.githubusercontent.com/webgeodatavore/qgis-class-diagram/master/diagramme_principal.png

Searchable documentation of QGIS and PyQGIS classes (by SourcePole): http://geoapis.sourcepole.com

For example, properties and methods of the `QgsGeometry` class are here: http://geoapis.sourcepole.com/qgispyapi-qgsgeometry/

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[geoapis.sourcepole](http://geoapis.sourcepole.com) doesn't exists anymore. Here are new ressources for [QGIS Python API Documentation](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/)